# Accuracy of setTimeout in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, settimeout

I'm building a metronome in React Native. After playing a click, I set a `setTimeout` for the next click. The timing however, is awful.

I did the following quick test:

```
let time = (new Date()).getTime() + 50;

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(time - (new Date()).getTime());
}, 50)
```

Ideally, I should get 0 in the console. While running this outside React Native in Chrome Dev Tools, I get -1, sometimes -2 (ms). This is an acceptable result.

Running this inside React Native using the Simulator on macOS I get values between 0 and -100. This clearly is not acceptable.

Does someone know if this is due to the inaccuracy of `setTimeout` or the inaccuracy of `(new Date()).getTime()`? Can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've investigated almost every React Native solution for playing audio and various approaches of using JavaScript's `setTimeout`/`setInterval`, but none of them were satisfactory in terms of time stability and accuracy.

Probably the only way to go at the moment is to glue some native module [like this one](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/HelloMetronome/Introduction/Intro.html) to the JS side, as described in the [RN Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html). This gives a pretty decent result, but is iOS only, of course.

Comment: I had the same experience using non-native code. Glueing native code is really the only solution at the moment.

Comment: Did you guys ever find a different approach now that so many years have passed?

Answer (score 8):

The delay that you configure for `setTimeout` and `setInterval` should never be thought of as an exact delay time. They represent the "minimum" amount of time that you'll wait before the function is executed. This is because the user-agent places the callback into the event queue when the time has elapsed, but if the user-agent is still working on some other task, the callback will sit there.

You should also know that there is a built-in absolute minimum time that you are never going to be able to go under of roughly 9-14ms. This is due to the internals of the user-agent.

Comment: Not to mention, most devices use a 60Hz clock for tracking the current time, so constructs like `new Date()` can be off by as much as 16ms.  If you need higher accuracy, you'll need to use a high resolution timer to measure clock delta.  That would be [performance.now()](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/08/When-milliseconds-are-not-enough-performance-now).

Comment: Clear answer, thanks! How would someone implement a metronome then... (or any other app that needs exact timing) ?

Comment: performance.now() solves the problem of getting the exact time. Setting an accurate timeout however, is not possible with performance.now(), is it? This could be a non-fixable issue, as React Native runs on a single thread. A quick google points me to http://www.hamsters.io/, could this help?

Comment: Update: performance.now() isn't available in React Native, and hamster.io doesn't work for React Native on iOS.

Comment: I'm not really sure something like this could be done via client-code. It may have to be a downloadable app.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, using React Native.

Comment: I'm referring to something written in C or Objective C, where you utilize the OS to get the work done. Does React work this way?

Comment: A React Native app is written in JavaScript and JSX and builds to a fully native (but single threaded) downloadable app. Your comment made me look up this https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html, this could help for my time critical tasks!! And I wouldn't have to rewrite my whole app in e.g. Swift.

Comment: Sounds promising.

Comment: I'm not sure about the "minimum amount" thing, for me setTimeout sometimes fires earlier than its interval.

Comment: @MoHaKa How are you bench marking that? I've never heard of timer callbacks firing sooner than their specified time. The minimum amount is well-known and (unfortunately) can't be reduced simply because of the latency between the user-agent and the host OS.

Comment: My problem could be completely different, but in my case setTimeout fires almost immediately every time i pass less than 1900 ms as an interval.

Comment: @MoHaKa Could it be that it just seems like that to you because other things are being delayed, that make it look like your setTimeout is firing sooner than it is?