# React Native audio does not play on time

Tags: react-native, timer, expo

I'm trying to make a metronome using react native, but I'm having trouble with the sound playback. I've used ExpoAV to play sound, but when I run it on the expo app it's very choppy and sometimes plays offbeat. I'm guessing the best way to play sounds on time is to use native modules? Is there a way to fix it right in react native?

Here's the code I use:

```js
const soundTimer = setInterval(() => {
    if (clickSound._loaded) {
        try {
            clickSound.replayAsync();
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
        }
    }
}, 60000/tempo);
```

**Edit:**
After some more intensive searching, I found an already answered question on here on Stack Overflow (I know, could've done that before...). Basically, the problem wasn't with the expo-av module, but with the JavaScript timer which is made to balance precision and performance on a single thread. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42100658/accuracy-of-settimeout-in-react-native).

Comment: Can you provide expo snack example?

Comment: I wish I could, but how do you import audio files into expo snack? I've never managed to import any files except javascript into it. Anyway, here's the link to the code, you can export it to expo cli and add click.mp3 (or wav) file to the root directory: https://snack.expo.io/@vincent.rodriguez/metro

Comment: the sounds might seem to play on time for non-drummers, but you can easily notice that the sound goes out of time for the higher tempos, for example, try setting the tempo to 240.

Answer (score 2):

I created the demo: https://snack.expo.io/SJSNohTYS

Changed the workflow of the code with useEffect and async await.

Comment: Thanks! But the timing is still all over the place, the clicks go in and out of time :( I tried loading several instances of the same sound into an array and iterating through the array for each click, but the problem is still there :// Could it be because of me running it through the expo app and not compiling it to run natively?

Comment: May be, please run snack  from updated answer (another link)

Comment: This seems to work better, but it still starts going off time at any tempo higher than 180 :(

Comment: In release mode i guess will  be fine.

Comment: I did run it in production mode

Comment: try to replace the await clickSound.replayAsync(); to 
                  await clickSound.setPositionAsync(0);
                await clickSound.playAsync();

Comment: It's even worse when using setPositionAsync and playAsync functions

Comment: You can try another way: setIsLoopingAsync(true) with sample that have some recorded silent

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the best solution here. Thanks!