# Precision timing in React / React Native / momentJS - length of a second differs depending on device

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I am building a React Native app for Android that has a dependency on durations of time and accurately creating actions at certain points in time.

Given the below code I have found that the length of a second changes depending on the device that is running it:

```js
interval.current = setInterval(() => {
  const now = moment().valueOf();
  console.log('now', now);
}, 1000);
```

If I run clocks based on the value of `now` which is a unix time stamp in milliseconds, the clocks deviate over time by a degree that is too much given the importance of time in the app.

I have analysed this on Google Pixel 2 XL and Samsung A10 devices. Surprisingly, despite the cheaper nature of the Samsung, it is much more accurate. You can see that for this 20 seconds of data, the Pixel deviates by 168ms where as the Samsung is just 6:

[image]

I don't understand why this is happening and want to find a better solution. Is there a way to access precise system or network time? Or is there a better approach to achieving precise timing on the client side?

TIA.

Comment: Try `Date.now()` instead of `moment().valueOf();`

Comment: Thanks @tarkh - unfortunately that seems to be very similar or worse.

Comment: Ok, keep in mind that you doing `console.log` here for debugging, but this function may create some delays. Try to push results to some array, then `console.log` them after all loops is done

Comment: Ok thanks - I'll try that but I can see the clocks go out of sync on the devices as well. I think it's related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42100658/accuracy-of-settimeout-in-react-native .

Answer (score 2):

JS timers like `setTimeout` or `setInterval` can't give you strict result. To measure time exactly you need to use timestamp with `Date.now()` or similar and compare it to the previous timestamp. You can use `setTimeout`, but do some calculations to figure out fluctuations and compensate them. Have a look at code below, which runs operation each second... You can see some fluctuations there, but they stays static and doesn't grow:

```js
const start = Date.now();
const cycles = 60;
let i = 0;

const delay = (ms = 1000) => {
  i++;
  const now = Date.now();
  const diff = now - start - i*1000;
  console.log(`Cycle ${i} fluctuation: ${diff}`);
  setTimeout(() => {
    // Compensate diff
    if(i < cycles) delay(1000-diff);
  }, ms);
}

// Run clock
setTimeout(delay, 1000);
```

Comment: Hi @tarkh, thanks for the answer - that's a great solution but I'm having problems implementing it React - I think it's because of the asynchronous nature of updating state? I could be wrong. Every time I measure the timing deviation there is 30 or 50 (or another amount) added on to the measurement of the deviation when compared to the true deviation. I've created a code sandbox to demo it: https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-http-kfzgy?file=/src/App.js
You can see even though when the deviation is small, the deviation logs show a greater amount. What could be causing this issue?